# how do i set up oracle instant client on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc, sqlplus, zabbix

so I'm trying to monitor oracle database by ODBC on zabbix, but my zabbix server is ubuntu 18.04 and I really confused because oracle is using rpm.

i do this step by step to configure oracle instant client:

https://sudonull.com/post/110401-Monitoring-Oracle-Database-through-ODBC-in-Zabbix

but while im trying to install sqlplus I got confused because of tnsnames.ora,

on tutorial he said to create a connection to the database with the name TESTDB for example, it's look like this:

> TESTDB =
> (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oratestdb)(PORT = 1521))
> (CONNECT_DATA =
> (SERVER = DEDICATED)
> (SERVICE_NAME = testdb)
> )
> )

so I made it exactly look like above, I do config /etc/hosts too but it got this error "TNS NO LISTENER" while trying to connect sqlplus.

I try to start lsnrctl but apparently it doesn't have lsnrctl.service

my question is,

- is it "TESTDB" something that i just made up or it should be the name of database on oracle database?
- when you finally try login in "sqlplus example/example@example" is it using user and password from oracle database that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it "TESTDB" something that i just made up or it should be the name
> of database on oracle database?

Taking your own example

```
TESTDB = -- you can give any name of your wish here 
       (DESCRIPTION = 
         (ADDRESS =  -- following 3 fields are details of DB server
            (PROTOCOL = TCP)
            (HOST = oratestdb)
            (PORT = 1521)
         ) 
         (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
            (SERVICE_NAME = testdb) -- This is the service name of the DB on given server
         ) 
       )
```

> when you finally try login in "sqlplus example/example@example" is it
> using user and password from oracle database that you have?

Yes this is the password of oracle DB user

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@TESTDB
```

Comment: I got error "ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrecty specified", 
I already set ORACLE_HOME, should i add ORACLE_SID too?